# Editing device manager using powershell

Tags: powershell, device-manager, wasp

Part of my work routine involves frequently enabling/disabling network adapters in the device manager, which is tedious and time consuming.
I am learning PowerShell, and want to write a simple script that automatically enables/disables the network adapter.

I am trying to use the WASP snap-in, which doesn't seem too difficult, but I cannot get it to work.

So far I have:

```
    # Launch the Device Manager
    $deviceManager = Show-ControlPanelItem -Name "Device Manager"

    # Display all currently open windows. Device Manager should display as 'mmc'
    Select-Window | ft -auto

    # Select Device Manager as the active window
    Select-Window mmc | Set-WindowActive

    # Send input to device manager
    Select-Window mmc | Send-Keys "{TAB}"
    Select-Window mmc | Send-Keys "n"
```

If the keyboard inputs are read properly, Network Adapter should be highlighted in Device Manager.
Instead, the device manager is opened and is active, but otherwise nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? How do I send keyboard input properly using WASP? WASP is not required, I am open to other tools if a superior option is available.

Answer (score 3):

Try working with `WMI` instead:

This will give you a list of  your adapters:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter
```

You can use a filter on `Name` to isolate a single adapter and assign the object to a variable:

```
$adapter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%MyAdapterName%'"
```

Then, you should be able to call `disable`, `enable`, `reset`, etc. on the object:

```
$adapter.disable()
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!
I was having a little trouble getting the second line to work, and while researching it I came across this simple cmdlet that does the job:
`Disable-NetAdapter -Name 'NIC Name'` (requires Admin priviledges)
WMI seems to be more robust though, so I will probably use it instead